# Using onListItemClick with Backendless

Tags: android, listview, hashmap, backendless

in my application it is possible to retrieve a list of books saved on the server. I show the books in a Listview and now I try to give the users of my application a detailed overview of the selected (by onListItemClick) book with name, releasedate, author,... But in this case I don't know how to transfer the selected book and its data to my BookDetailActivity. I can't handle the Map BackendlessCollection in onListItemClick...

This is my BookAdapter:

```
public BooksAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Books> book_list )
{
    super( context, resource, book_list );
    mResource = resource;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
}

@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ){
    View view = convertView == null ? mInflater.inflate( mResource, parent, false ) : convertView;    
    TextView booksNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.bookName );
    TextView booksReleaseView = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.bookRelease );
    TextView booksAuthorView = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.bookAuthor );
    Books item = getItem( position );
    booksNameView.setText( item.getName() );
    objectIdView.setText( item.getObjectId() );
    booksReleaseView.setText( item.getRelease() );
    booksAuthorView.setText( item.getAuthor() );
    return view;
}
```

This is the main code of my BooksListActivity:

```
//inside the onCreate
adapter = new BooksAdapter( BooksListActivity.this, R.layout.list_item_books, totalBooks );
setListAdapter( adapter );

Backendless.Data.of( Books.class ).find( query, new LoadingCallback<BackendlessCollection<Books>>( this , getString( R.string.loading_books ), true )
    {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse( BackendlessCollection<Books> booksBackendlessCollection )
        {   book_list = booksBackendlessCollection;
            addMoreItems( booksBackendlessCollection );
            super.handleResponse( booksBackendlessCollection );}
    } );
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById( android.R.id.list );

//outside the onCreate
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long ObjectId) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, ObjectId);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, BookDetailActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

At last I would show the details of the selected book in my BookDetailActivity as typical TextViews.

I really hope you can help me!
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data to the next activity by using Intent extras. All you need to do is use `intent.putExtra()` to pass the data.

In your case, inside your `onListItemClick` here's what you need to do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, BookDetailActivity.class);
Book book = totalBooks.get(i);
i.putExtra("title", book.title);
i.putExtra("content", book.content);
startActivity(i);
```

And eventually in the `BookDetailActivity` activity, you can read the data by calling `getIntent().getExtras()`

Or,

you can pass the entire `Book` object using a Bundle:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, BookDetailActivity.class);
Book book = totalBooks.get(i);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("book", book);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```